# What is correct mongoid relation for a parentless object that EVENTUALLY belongs to something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have 2 objects:

1. Banana
2. Basket

A banana can exist without a basket

But a basket must contain a banana.

I did:

Class Banana
  embedded_in

Class Basket
  embeds Banana

**BUT**

When I try to create a Banana, mongoid complains about not having a basket.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

> A banana can exist without a basket

That makes it a first-level citizen, so embedding is not really an option (one could create 'shadow baskets' for bananas that aren't in a basket, but that idea is too creepy at 1AM over here. Not recommended).

It sounds like there could be more than one banana in a basket, but even if not, turning the aggregation around doesn't seem to make sense (i.e. putting the basket 'in' the banana). It doesn't model reality so it's probably a bad design.

> a basket must contain a banana.

You will have to ensure this in your client code and have both bananas and baskets as first-level citizens:

```
basket { _id : 7871, ... }
banana { _id : 4545, basket_id : 7871, ... }
```

or

```
basket { _id : 7871, banana_ids : [ 4545, ... ] }
banana { _id : 4545, ... }
```

The second variant makes it easier to enforce the rule that a basket must have a banana, while the first makes it easier to ensure that one banana is not in two baskets at the same time.

Ensuring that these criteria are met isn't trivial because mongodb doesn't support transactions and you can't atomically modify more than one document. Your client code will have to deal with this, e.g. through locking.